# How to convert datetime of format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD to UTC datetime?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have string of format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD` where `TZD` is `-hh:mm` or `+hh:mm`. Example: `2020-09-18T10:27:29-07:00`. How can I convert this to UTC datetime in python?

`2020-09-18T10:27:29-07:00` is local time. I want to convert all local time to UTC datetime.

What I tried :

```
time = "2020-09-18T10:27:29-07:00"
datetime.fromisoformat(time).utcnow()
```

This does't seem to work

Comment: From the datetime module, import timezone, then you can convert like `datetime.fromisoformat(t).astimezone(timezone.utc)`

Comment: It doesn't work. If you convert the time given above, in UTC it still should be 2020-09-18T10:27:29. But your way gives UTC+7.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work *how you expect*? - 10h at UTC-7 is 17h at UTC+0, that's just how UTC offsets work.

Comment: Sorry what you did was the right one. Does this take into consideration Daytime saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to convert?**

To convert a timestamp with a UTC offset to UTC (offset=0), use

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t = "2020-09-18T10:27:29-07:00"
t_UTC = datetime.fromisoformat(t).astimezone(timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 17, 27, 29, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

**What about DST transitions?**

Daylight saving time transitions are represented in the UTC offset. For example for time zone America/LA, a DST transition would look like

```
"2020-03-08T00:00:00-08:00"
"2020-03-08T01:00:00-08:00"
"2020-03-08T03:00:00-07:00"
"2020-03-08T04:00:00-07:00"
```

Using the code above to convert to UTC, the timestamps would show as

```
"2020-03-08T08:00:00+00:00"
"2020-03-08T09:00:00+00:00"
"2020-03-08T10:00:00+00:00"
"2020-03-08T11:00:00+00:00"
```

**How can I get back the original UTC offset?**

That means converting UTC to the time in a certain time zone - so you'd need a time zone for this, especially to handle DST transitions. Ex:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9; for Python <3.9 use dateutil.tz.gettz
    
l = ["2020-03-08T08:00:00+00:00", "2020-03-08T09:00:00+00:00",
     "2020-03-08T10:00:00+00:00", "2020-03-08T11:00:00+00:00"]

for t in l:
    print(datetime.fromisoformat(t).astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles')))
    
2020-03-08 00:00:00-08:00
2020-03-08 01:00:00-08:00
2020-03-08 03:00:00-07:00
2020-03-08 04:00:00-07:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The python package *python-dateutil* will do the trick ([docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse)):

```py
from dateutil import parser

time = "2020-09-18T10:27:29-07:00"
result = parser.isoparse(time)
```

Install dateutil with

```py
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: It returns `datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 10, 27, 29, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))` I am understanding what the tzinfo here is.

Comment: `tzinfo` is the timezone offset from UTC in seconds

Comment: Python's standard lib already does this efficiently, no need for a third-party lib. Also, the OP wants to convert, not just parse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my computer could not find a version of dateutil to install to test the previous response. Here's a way of implementing the new time zone into the time string (ISO 8601) in Python but it can be extended to other languages also (just change the syntax). And I also fetch the date and time (from the computer), instead of just typing the string in. Then convert it. This is especially useful for weather, news, stock/crypto APIs where you can gather loads of data very quickly. You can now convert their time into a much more comprehensible format. [Click here to check out 50 of the most popular APIs from rapidapi.com](https://rapidapi.com/blog/most-popular-api/)

```
import datetime#this library has the commands, you need to install the library if your compiler can't find it (pip install datetime or pip3 install datetime)
    
dt=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
#dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")#already in correct timezone
dt+='Z'#ADD A Z TO THE END FOR CORRECT ISO 8601
dt=dt[:19]#cut the string down to the minimum requirements

print(dt+'  UTC  (ISO 8601 format)')

tiz=float(dt[11]+dt[12])#hour is the 11th and 12th characters in this string
tiz-=8#Pacific Standard Time is UTC-8 (put += if it's ahead instead of -=)
if tiz>23:#upper limit for hours is 23
    tiz-=24
else:
    if tiz<0:#lower limit for hours is 0
        tiz+=24
tiz=int(tiz)
if tiz<10:
    #tiz=' '+str(tiz)#easier to read the hour w/out leading zero
    tiz='0'+str(tiz)#leading zero necessary for ISO 8601
#print(tiz)#check the hour change because of the timezone
dt=dt[:11]+tiz+dt[13:]#replace the hour

print(dt+'  UTC-8  (ISO 8601 format) Easier to read hour when summed with timezone already')

print('on '+dt[5:8]+dt[8:10]+'-'+dt[0:4]+' (M-D-Y) at '+dt[11:19]+' (H:M:S)'+'  UTC-8  Easier to distinguish month and day!')

if dt[7:9]=='01' or dt[7:9]==' 1':#ordinal numbers for days
    da='st'
else:
    if dt[7:9] == '02' or dt[7:9] == ' 2':
        da = 'nd'
    else:
        if dt[7:9] == '03' or dt[7:9] == ' 3':
            da = 'rd'
        else:
            da = 'th'
dtm=['Jan','Feb','Mrc','Apr','May','Jun','Jly','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
dt=dt[0:5]+dtm[(int(dt[5:7])-1)]+dt[8:19]# convert month # to name

print('on '+dt[5:8]+'-'+dt[8:10]+da+'-'+dt[0:4]+' at '+dt[11:20]+'  UTC-8  Even easier to distinguish month and day!')#EASIER TO READ!
```

Output:
2020-12-25T02:33:04Z  UTC  (ISO 8601 format)
2020-12-25T18:33:04Z  UTC-8  (ISO 8601 format) Easier to read hour when summed with timezone already
on 12-25-2020 (M-D-Y) at 18:33:04 (H:M:S)  UTC-8  Easier to distinguish month and day!
on Dec-25th-2020 at 18:33:04  UTC-8  Even easier to distinguish month and day!